# Question about choosing a font got "on hold"

Tags: discussion, support

My question about considerations to make when choosing the right font
for desktop applications got "on hold".

The question can be viewed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364432/what-default-font-to-choose-for-desktop-applications)

What can I do to improve the question and get it off the "on hold" stack?

Answer (score 8):

Your question would perhaps be better suited to [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) as it is, well, more UX related than programming.

Closed as Primarily Opinion Based makes perfect sense too as a font preference would differ from user to user, even if you are aiming for objective reasons for selecting a font.

Comment: But choosing a font in the process of designing an user interface is rationale based, not by a process of "emm, this looks good". At least it should be. And that is what the question is about.

Comment: @MareInfinitus I agree, but the question would still be better on UX. SO is for the programming side of things, not UI.

Comment: There are lots of points where those two have commons. And lots of questions on SO have nothing to do with algorithms or programming.

Comment: @MareInfinitus If those questions truly are not about coding or coding tools, they should probably be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @MareInfinitus What's opinion based for coders, may be rational process for UX designers. From code point of view only completeness and validity of font file really matter. Oh, and sometimes size. But that's not what your question was about.

Comment: Okay, I give it a try on UX